# Nothing happens on form submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I applied tinyMCE to a text area in my sites admin area.
Now there is a page "create category" and and page "edit category."

In edit category, there is a drop-down of the categories, I select one and the text area for category description is filled in with AJAX and a tinyMCE function:_

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(responce);
```

The category description is filled into the text area on which tinyMCE is applied. But when I click submit, NOTHING happens at all.Similarly, on the create category page, there is no drop down, but when you click submit, nothing happens at all.

This problem does not occur when tinyMCE is not applied. But on the edit category page, it was submitting but not filling in the text area with the category description, when instead of

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(responce);
```

I used

```
$("#lang_description").html(responce);
```

in the callback function for jQuery AJAX.

So the main problem is that the forms are not being submitted and that was the story.

Someone suggested to use the tinyMCE function getContent before I post but I dont understand where and how I would do that.

Comment: I noticed "response" is incorrectly spelled as "responce"... is it spelled consistently throughout your code?

Comment: @Sparky672, dont worry about that it's spelt right everywhere, it's the variable which holds what comes back from the AJAX call.

Comment: I'm not _worried_ about anything... I'm trying to help you by simply asking if your spelling was **consistent**.  In other words, if you spell it one way over here and a different way other there, it's not going to work.

Comment: I know, I know, I didnt really think you were worried, I just like to spell response like that.(Although yes, I should spell it properly) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've faced a situation once like yours and what I did that was first i set in `tinyMCE.init`

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact", // Used exact
    elements : "page_content", // I gave the textarea id and name 'page_content'
    ...
});
```

Then I've wrote a function as follows

```
function get_page_content()
{
    var ed = tinyMCE.get('page_content');
    return ed.getContent();
}
```

Then inside my form submit event handler/function I just did

```
$('#page_content').val(get_page_content()); // I populated my textarea (id=page_content) before the form submission
```

I received the data using `$page_content=$_POST['page_content']` in my php script

**Update:** May be you can use

```
var ed=tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); // when you didn't set the mode : "exact" in init function
```

**Reference:** [**getContent**](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent) and [**setContent**](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent)

May be not a solution but If this helps then I'll be glad to know. Also notice Sparky672's comment.

Comment: thanks alot it worked! + i removed the required attribute off of the text area and it worked, I guess it didnt show the text area highlighted in red like it usually would because it gets converted into an iframe because of tinyMCE, and that's why the form was not submitting, but it is updating the category properly somehow which is really confusing, but it works. :)